# fixed div size to screen size and when div content size increase horizontal scrollbar appear using ng-slimscroll horizontal-scroll="true"

Tags: html, angularjs, slimscroll

```
<div class="test3" ng-slimscroll horizontal-scroll="true" size="5px" opacity="0.4">contentssimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry's.LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry's.LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry's. 
</div>
```

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/gobLw3w7/)

when above div exceed screen width limits than horizontal scrollbar appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div style="width: 100%; position: absolute;left: 0;right: 0">
        <div ng-slimscroll horizontal-scroll="true" size="5px" opacity="0.4">
            contentssimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry's.LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry's.LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry's.
            LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry's.LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry's.LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry's.LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry's.LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry's.LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry's.LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry's.LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry's.LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry's.
            LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry's.LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry's.LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry's.LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry's.LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry's.LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry's.LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry's.LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry's.LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry's.
            LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry's.LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry's.LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry's.LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry's.LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry's.LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry's.LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry's.LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry's.LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry's.
            LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry's.LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry's.LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry's.LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry's.LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry's.LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry's.LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry's.LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry's.LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry's.
        </div>
    </div>
```

i found my answer its work for me